# Customized Scope in Aws Cognito Token generation OIDC

Tags: amazon-cognito, openid-connect, scopes, idp

We are using cognito for authentication and session management. We have added one external idp server which uses oauth as OIDC identity provider. For token generation, that IDP has different scopes, which gives access to various resources needed by our server. But when using cognito as authentication mechanism, we are not able provide those scopes in get token call. Is there any way to:

1. add specific scopes in get token call to another IDP via cognito?
2. If yes, is there a way to get that access token into our server to later call that identity provider if we want to get information about user
3. If not, is there a way to skip access token call and get authorization code so that access token can be retrieved by custom code in our server?
4. Is there a way to show consent popup to user while doing all this when getting a token?

Comment: @MistGun No, We solved it by building our own SSO workflow and then by adding custom handler in cognito to create a new session in cognito

Answer (score 0):

There was no way to do it in AWS cognito. To do this, we built our own SSO workflow with IDP and then using custom handler added session to cognito.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).